# Tensorflow ConvNet: Doesn't converge when using multiple GPUs with Cuda

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, conv-neural-network

I have the following code implementing a 2-layers ConvNet in Tensorflow. It works perfectly when I use it on a single GPU setup as below:

```
            learning_rate = 0.001
            row_size = self.features_size[0]
            col_size = self.features_size[1]
            conv1_size = self.h_layers[0]
            conv2_size = self.h_layers[1]

            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, row_size, col_size])
            y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_class])

            weights = { 'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([conv1_size[0], conv1_size[1], 1, 32])),
                        'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([conv2_size[0], conv2_size[1], 32, 64])),
                        'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([row_size*col_size*4, 1024])),
                        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, self.n_class]))}

            biases = {  'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
                        'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
                        'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
                        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_class]))}

            def conv2d(x, W):
                return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

            def maxpool2d(x):
                return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

            def get_available_gpus(**args):
                local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
                return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']

            def conv_net(x, W, B, dropout_rate, is_training):

                x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2], 1])
                conv1 = conv2d(x, W['W_conv1'])
                conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1 + B['b_conv1'])
                conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

                conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, W['W_conv2']) + B['b_conv2'])
                conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

                fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv2)
                fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc1, W['W_fc']) + B['b_fc'])
                fc1 = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, rate=dropout_rate, training=is_training)

                output = tf.matmul(fc1, W['out']) + B['out']

           ########  THIS PART IS SPECIFIC TO SINGLE-GPU #######

           logits_train = conv_net(x, weights, biases, self.dropout_rate, is_training=True)
           prediction = tf.argmax(logits_train, axis=1)
           cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_train, labels=y))
           train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

           #####################################################

        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
        prediction, cross_entropy, train_step, x, y = self.set_model()
        sess = tf.Session()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
        fetch = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run([fetch])



            for epoch in range(self.epoch):
                epoch_loss = 0
                i = 0
                while i < len(features):
                    start = i
                    end = i + self.batch_size
                    batch_x = np.array(features[start:end])
                    batch_y = np.array(labels[start:end])

                    _, c = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                    epoch_loss += c
                    i += self.batch_size
                print('Global Step:', sess.run(global_step), ',  Epoch:', epoch, ' completed out of', self.epoch, 'loss:', epoch_loss)
```

This works well on a single GPU but I wanted to make it work using multiple nvidia Tesla k80 GPUs with Cuda.

I modified the part calling the optimizer as per TensorFlow documentation such that:

```
            ################  MULTI-GPU MODIFICATION ############

            gpu_list = get_available_gpus()
            tower_grads = []
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
            if gpu_list:
                print(gpu_list)
                for gpu in gpu_list:
                    with tf.device(gpu):
                        logits_train = conv_net(x, weights, biases, self.dropout_rate, is_training=True)
                        prediction = tf.argmax(logits_train, axis=1)
                        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_train, labels=y))
                        grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)#, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
                        tower_grads.append(grads)

                grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
                apply_gradient_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
                train_step = tf.group(apply_gradient_op)
            #################################################
```

Even though this also works, and uses the resource of all my GPUs simultaneously, it fails to converge (the loss remains the same after hundreds of iterations where using single-GPU approach on same problem converge rapidly).

I believe the problem comes from the agregation of the tower-gradients, but since I use the exact function provided by TensorFlow in [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) also documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) I can't imagine the 
`average_gradients()` method should be the problem. Anyway, here it is:

```
        def average_gradients(tower_grads):
            """
            Provided by Tensorflow doc 
            """
            average_grads = []
            for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
                # Note that each grad_and_vars looks like the following:
                #   ((grad0_gpu0, var0_gpu0), ... , (grad0_gpuN, var0_gpuN))
                grads = []
                for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
                    # Add 0 dimension to the gradients to represent the tower.
                    expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)

                    # Append on a 'tower' dimension which we will average over below.
                    grads.append(expanded_g)

                # Average over the 'tower' dimension.
                grad = tf.concat(axis=0, values=grads)
                grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)

                # Keep in mind that the Variables are redundant because they are shared
                # across towers. So .. we will just return the first tower's pointer to
                # the Variable.
                v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
                grad_and_var = (grad, v)
                average_grads.append(grad_and_var)
                return average_grads
```

Any idea where the fail of convergence might come from?

I was also considering the fact that I don't split the batch according to the number of GPUs as I should do... Any input on that?

Comment: Looks like the last line of your last code block should be indented to the left (i.e. "return" should be outside the "for" block). That seems like it could be a bit of an issue for correctly aggregating the gradients.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with CUDA programming, which is why I have now removed the tag *twice*. Please do not re-add it.

Comment: Not cuda-programming Indeed, but since the issue comes from calling multiple cuda GPUs from TF I believed it was worth mentioning adding the cuda tag. It is not your typical cuda programming question I agree though.

Comment: @AllenLavoie thanks, that was indeed one of the mistakes. The other being that I didn’t pass the variables to each tower. I still have to figure something out and try to post a clear solution.